# Grep a list of files that contains specified string and get output with file name & desired data

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have a list of files for ex.

```
user1.txt
user2805927.txt
admin.txt
```

and on each file there are some datas like:

```
unwanted data line1
unwanted data line2
unwanted data line n

Usage · 220
other lines that I don't need
```

And I want to get just the number "220" and it is different on each file

One of the problems, there's a symbol `·  ALT CODE + 250`
that I can't write it on Putty

Is there any way to get an output filename + data, like:

```
users1.txt | 220
user2805927.txt | 85
admin.txt | 18
```

Comment: How about doing regex that finds `Usage` then skips all non-digits after and finally capture the number?

Comment: Use `grep -o ...` and that should do it

Comment: @PM77-1 Yeah, condition is to get data that before has the string 'Usage', but this symbol ALT + 250, isn't allowing me

Comment: @Dominique can you explain me the code on answer?

Comment: Do not think about the special character - simply skip it as non-digit.

Comment: @PM77-1 could you explain me the full code?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/19a398/2

Answer (score 1):

You *can* `grep` for an arbitrary character code (with a couple of exceptions -- 0 and 255 are used internally in GNU `grep`).

```
xargs grep -o $'\xfa.*' -m 1 <filenames.txt
```

The Bash "C-style" string `$'...'` lets you use a hex character code `\xfa` (equivalent to decimal 250) and `grep -o` says to only print the match, not the whole line. With `-m 1` we limit to the first match in each file, in case there would be several. `xargs` says to run `grep` with the file names in the file as command-line arguments; this causes `grep` to also print the file name in front of each match.

```
users1.txt:· 220
user2805927.txt:· 85
admin.txt:· 18
```

Post-processing this output left as an exercise. (If you have `grep -P` you can put a `\\K` after the hex code to exclude it from the match easily.)

Here's a `sed` variation:

```
xargs -n 1 -i sed -n '/^Usage [^0-9]*/!d;s//{} | /p;q' {} <filenames.txt
```

If the current line doesn't match the regular expression, delete it and start over with the next line. Otherwise, replace the match with the current file name (`xargs -i` replaces `{}`with the file name) and print the line, then quit processing the current file. `xargs -n 1` says to run a new invocation of the `sed` command for each filename (though this is required by `-i` anyway so implied anyway.)

Comment: I secretly speculate that the character you see doesn't actually have character code 250. On modern systems, it's probably a Unicode character, encoded as UTF-8. Adapting this answer to that should not be too hard if you actually understand what this means. If not, this box is much too small to explain it.

Comment: Or you can `grep -P -o -m 1 '^Usage\s+[^\s\d]+\s+\K\d+'` and not worry about the precise character code. Or the same with `sed` if you don't have `grep -P`.